# Why composite jsf tag does not call listener on ajax call?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, composite-component

I recently moved some code from a view to a composite jsf tag to make my code cleaner, but just realized that an ajax call is no longer working.

The browser makes the update, and I can see the data displaying, but the method just don't get called a all.

I've the following code as a tag:

```
<composite:interface> 
 <composite:attribute name="viewBean" type="org.example.view.RegistroMunicipalView" required="true" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
 <saimTags:dataFlag viewBean="#{cc.attrs.viewBean}"/>
  <p:selectOneMenu  styleClass="source_select" value="#{cc.attrs.viewBean}" >
      <f:selectItems value="#{cc.attrs.viewBean.registros}" var="registro" 
                     itemValue="#{registro.idRegistro}"
                     itemLabel="#{registro.nombre}"></f:selectItems>
      <p:ajax listener="#{cc.attrs.viewBean.registroChanged()}" oncomplete="checkForData()" update="@(.section_content)"/>

   </p:selectOneMenu>
</composite:implementation>
```

This one as the class with the method to be called:

```
public abstract class RegistroMunicipalView extends MunicipalView {
 private Integer idRegistro;
 public abstract void registroChanged();
}
```

And like this the implementation of the tag

```
<saimTags:displayRegistro viewBean="#{informacionMunicipalView}"/>
```

Any clue of what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused because of a wrong attribute value in the selectOneMenu, 
it was pointing to the bean instead of the property idRegistro which caused a silent failure, with this change the method is now called correctly.

Before:

```
<p:selectOneMenu  styleClass="source_select" value="#{cc.attrs.viewBean}" >
```

After:

```
<p:selectOneMenu  styleClass="source_select" value="#{cc.attrs.viewBean.idRegistro}" >
```